# Solving a equation involving complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

The question is to find out all the complex numbers $z$ that satisfy the equation $z+c|z+1|+i=0$ for every $c \geq 1$

I tried to take the complex conjugate of the equation and adding the two equations to get

$$\bar{z} + z +2c|z+1|=0$$

I couldn't proceed after this. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the problem is this:

> For each $c\in[1,+\infty)$, to solve the equation $z+c|z+1|+i=0$.

Note that$$z+c|z+1|+i=0\iff c|z+1|=-z-i.$$Since $c|z+1|\in[0,+\infty)$, any solution must be of the form $-a-i$, with $a\in[0,+\infty)$. So, the problem now is to solve the equation$$c|-a+1-i|=a,$$which is equivalent to$$c^2\bigl((1-a)^2+1\bigr)=a^2.$$ This is just a quadratic equation in $a$.

Comment: Why are you assuming $c\geq 1$? The equation has a perfectly good solution for $c=0$, for example...

Comment: @5xum I am assuming that $c\geqslant1$ because the OP wrote “for every $c\geqslant1$”.

Comment: Oh dear. Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch**: Observe since $z = x+iy$ then 
\begin{align}
0=\big|(z+i)+c|z+1|\big| = \sqrt{|y+1|^2+(x+c|z+1|)^2}
\end{align}
which means $y = -1$ and 
\begin{align}
x = -c|x-i+1| = -c\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1} \ \ \implies& \ \ x^2= c((x+1)^2+1)\\
\implies&\ \ x^2 = c(x^2+2x+2)\\
\implies&\ \ (1-c)x^2-2x-2 = 0. 
\end{align}